# How to make an algorithm for forming a query string from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to solve a problem dealing with forming a query parameter string from an array. The array in question is a dynamic filtering condition array (formed by user's choices) that defines what objects a list of objects holds. The query parameter string is passed to an API, which returns the filtered list.

What is needed is an algorithm that can solve this kind of array to form a string out of it. The array consists of: 1) the basic filtering arrays and 2) the separators (`"and"`, `"or"`). The basic filtering array is of form `[key, operator, value]`. All the separators should be defined accordingly; `"or"` with same property keys (eg. "name") should become values separated with a comma (ie., `"name=a,b"`). Also, there's a `&|` to denote a different kind of `"or"` separator (used to combine filters of different keys, since the `"name=a,b,c"` syntax can't accomplish that), but more on that later.

For example, consider this array:

```
['name', '=', 'aa']
'or'
['name', '=', 'bb']
'and',
[
 ['id', '=', 1],
 'or',
 ['id', '=', 2]
]
```

In this case, the query string should be formed like: `"name=aa,bb&id=1,2"`

In another example, let's define a filtering array with a negation:

```
'!',
[
 ['name', '=', 'aa'],
 'or',
 ['name', '=', 'bb']
]
```

The query string should be: `"name!=aa,bb"`.

The API supports a custom syntax where multiple different keys can be separated with an `"or"` (`"name=a &| id=2"`, where the `&|` denotes an `"or"`. Also, parentheses can be used to group filtering conditions (ie. `"name=a &| (name=b&id=1,2)"`).

Hopefully this gives some kind of picture of what I'm trying to accomplish. So the question is, how would you approach this problem? Some kind of divide and conquer algorithm perhaps? What would be the most efficient way to convert these sorts of arrays of arrays into query parameter strings? This converter algorithm would be used in many places, and so, it should respond rather quickly to user interaction.

Here's a more complex array:

```
['id', '=', 1],
'or',
[
 [
  ['state', '=', 'ready'],
  'or',
  ['state', '=', 'unhandled']
 ],
 'and',
 [
  ['name', '=', 'aa'],
  'or',
  ['name', '=', 'bb']
 ]
],
'and',
[
 '!',
 ['id', '=', 2]
],
'and',
[
 '!',
 ['id', '=', 3]
]
```

And the result string of that should be:

`id=1 |& (state=ready,unhandled&name=aa,bb) & id!=2,3`

Comment: what about `['id', '=', 1],
 'and',
 ['id', '=', 2]`?

Comment: How can you negate a group? Is `!` meant to be a string?

Comment: btw, why is the name part not grouped in an onw array?

Comment: "*"or" with same property keys (eg. "name") should become values separated with a comma*" - that's a special case and can be considered later. `name=a&|name=b` would work as well, right?

Comment: How long can your arrays be? If there are multiple `or`s and `and`s in your array, what's their precedence and associativity?

Comment: do you have operator precedences? are you gone?

Comment: @NinaScholz Same keys with an "and" separator should be ideally joined as an "or" ("id=1,2"). But these kinds of arrays are rare, so they're of secondary importance.

Comment: @NinaScholz  2) The name part is not grouped, because the filter array is provided by a 3rd party part of the software that may give array in that form. But yes, mostly the parts would be grouped. 3) The precedence is that same keys with an "or" separator should be handled first, then the "and" separators.

Comment: do you have some more complex data and the wanted result?

Comment: @Bergi 1) Yes, my bad. The `!` should be a string. Everything that follows it in the array or nested array below should be negated. 2) Yes,  `name=a&|name=b` would work as well, but a shorter syntax is preferred due to the API having its' limit on how long a query parameter string it can hande. `name=a,b` is much more concise form.

Comment: @Bergi the arrays can be quite long, according to how the user filters the data. The associativity follows the basic boolean logic: conditions inside the parentheses should be handled as a group. And De Morgan's laws should be applied to complex filters following a `!`, since everything after it in the same array should be negated.

Comment: I'd suggest multiple passes then, each of them a recursive tree traversal. 1) preprocess (convert linear operation lists to proper tree structure, apply demorgan) 2) join `or(=(…), =(…))` and `and(!=(…), !=(…))` where adjacent elements have the same names into comma values 3) join the whole tree into a string by converting `or` to `&|` and `and` to `&`, applying grouping parenthesis where necessary.

Comment: @NinaScholz I added a more complex example.